# Setting "task affinity" programmatically

Tags: android, manifest, affinity

is there a way to set the "task affinity" programmatically? I mean like with some Intent flag or sth? I didn't find anything about this being possible in the Android docs.

Setting the affinity in a static way in the AndroidManifest.xml with `android:taskAffinity` does not suit my needs.

Comment: Whenever launching an Activity, you can add affinity flags like so. Not sure if this is what you intended. 

   ```Intent intent = new Intent(this, IntroActivity.class);
    // These flags disable back-pressing back into the previous activity
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
    startActivity(intent);
    finish();```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android: Task affinity & Clear task](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21528508/android-task-affinity-clear-task)

Answer (score 5):

You cannot.

`taskAffinity` is contained by `ActivityInfo`, which is member of `Activity`.

[Source code of Activity](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/app/Activity.java)

```
public class Activity extends ContextThemeWrapper
    ...
    ... {
    // set by the thread after the constructor and before 
    // onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) is called.

    @UnsupportedAppUsage
    /*package*/ ActivityInfo mActivityInfo;
 }
```

And `ActivityInfo` has taskAffinity.

[Source code of ActivityInfo](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/content/pm/ActivityInfo.java)

```
/**
 * Information you can retrieve about a particular application
 * activity or receiver. This corresponds to information collected
 * from the AndroidManifest.xml's &lt;activity&gt; and
 * &lt;receiver&gt; tags.
 */
public class ActivityInfo extends ComponentInfo implements Parcelable {

   /**
    * The affinity this activity has for another task in the system.  The
    * string here is the name of the task, often the package name of the
    * overall package.  If null, the activity has no affinity.  Set from the
    * {@link android.R.attr#taskAffinity} attribute.
    */
    public String taskAffinity;
```

According to the comment of source code, information of `taskAffinity` is collected from `AndroidManifest.xml`. And there is no public method to set `mActivityInfo.taskAffinity`.

Answer (score -4):

Use this method :

```
finishAffinity();
```

Comment: He is asking about "setting affinity" not finishing affinity