# Android: Task affinity & Clear task

Tags: android, android-navigation, android-intent

I am having three modules - ModuleA, ModuleB, ModuleC

```
ModuleA - 1 activity
```

MainActivity - no task affinity

```
Module B - 3 activities
```

Activity_A
task affinity = "com.performance.poc.main"

Activity_B
task affinity = "com.performance.poc.main"

Activity_C 
task affinity = "com.performance.poc.main"

```
Module C - 1 activity
```

Activity_D - no task affinity

```
Navigation Case 1:
```

1. MainActivity
2. on btn Click - start Activity_A Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
3. on btn Click - start Activity_B
4. on btn Click - start Activity_C
5. on btn Click - start Activity_D Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK

   ***Expected Task Result:**    

   **Task com.performance.poc***
    Activity_D 
    MainActivity

   ***Task com.performance.poc.main*** 
   Activity_C
   Activity_B
   Activity_A

   Expected : on starting the Activity_D task com.performance.poc.main should be cleared. 
   Actual : Still Activity_A, Activity_B, Activity_C remains but MainActivity is cleared.

---

```
Navigation Case 2:
```

1. MainActivity
2. on btn Click - start Activity_A Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
3. on btn Click - start Activity_B
4. on btn Click - start Activity_C Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
5. on btn Click - start Activity_D Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK

***Expected Task Result:***

***Task com.performance.poc***    
Activity_D    
MainActivity

***Task com.performance.poc.main***

Activity_C    
Activity_B    
Activity_A

```
 Expected : on starting the Activity_C, in task com.performance.poc.main, Activity_A, Activity_B should be cleared. 
Actual :  Activity_A, Activity_B is cleared as expected.
```

My Question here is why in Case1, even though Activity_A, Activity_B, Activity_C are in same task and it is not clearing these and clearing MainActivity.

The Clear_Task should clear the existing task of the activity **from which startActivity is called with intent new_task and clear_task.**  or it will clear the task of target activity.

```
If it is Target activity, I need to clear the task of the leaving activity, is there any way to do it?
```

Comment: What is the package name in your manifest?

Comment: package="com.performance.poc"

Comment: And when you say "no task affinity" (for example on `MainActivity`) you mean that there is no `android:taskAffinity` in the `<activity>` tag, correct?

Comment: ya. you are right. taskAffinity attribute is not added for that activity and application tag also.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Setting `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK` will clear the **target task**.

You say that you need to clear the current task. You can do this by using an intermediate `Activity`. Just create a simple `Activity` that does the following in `onCreate()`:

```
Intent = new Intent(this, ActivityD.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(intent);
finish();
```

This simple Activity should have the same `taskAffinity` as `ActivityA, B and C`.

When `ActivityC` wants to start `ActivityD`, it should start this activity instead like this:

```
Intent = new Intent(this, SimpleActivity.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
startActivity(intent);
```

This will clear the current task and then `SimpleActivity` will launch `ActivityD` and finish, which will finish the task.

Comment: Thanks David. is there any Intent Flag, by which i can achieve it? Since I have a custom class (Navigation Controller) which controls all the Navigation and clearing activities based on config.xml placed in the application.

Comment: Sorry no. There is no `Intent` flag that you can set that will clear the current task if you are launching an `Activity` into another task. For that you will need a "delegate" or "proxy" activity like I described. Please also note that `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK` is only available on Android 3.0 and higher, so your app will not run on Android 2.2/2.3 (still represents more than 20% of the installed base of devices)

Comment: I am gonna use support library for Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK.   <br></br>  
Intent i = new Intent(this, Activity_C.class);
ComponentName cn = i.getComponent();
Intent mainIntent = IntentCompat.makeRestartActivityTask(cn);
startActivity(mainIntent);

Comment: Hmmm. Not sure that will work. Documentation indicates that this will relaunch the root activity (in your case `MainActivity`. Since your app has multiple tasks this may not do what you want. Also, I'm not sure that the behaviour of `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK` is fully/properly simulated in the compatibility library. Make sure you test all this.

Comment: Also, I hope you understand that if your app has multiple tasks it is often difficult/confusing for the user to go to the HOME screen and then return to your application using the list of recent tasks. Make sure that you test those conditions as well.

Comment: Is there any other way by which I can clear a set of activities while moving to other activity as described above ? without using taskAffinity (since creating multiple recent list for same app as you told)

Comment: Yes. In general you can set `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP` when launching an Activity. If this Activity is already in the stack then Android will finsh that Activity and all of the Activities on top of it in the stack, then launch a new instance of that Activity. If you also set an "extra" on the Intent that you use to start the Activity (for example "launchActivityX") then in `onCreate()` of the Activity that you just launched you can test for the existence of the "extra" and launch the new Activity accordingly.

Comment: Basically you delegate the launching of the target Activity to the one that you are clearing back to. I hope this is clear.